# Update Multiple Columns In one Execution

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='499' WHERE TypeOrModel = 'A130';
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='599' WHERE TypeOrModel = 'A140';
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='1899' WHERE TypeOrModel = 'Alpha Style';
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='1699' WHERE TypeOrModel = 'Amethyst';
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='899' WHERE TypeOrModel = 'T18';
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='1499' WHERE TypeOrModel = 'Ace_f100';
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='499' WHERE TypeOrModel ='Aura Fusion';
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='499' WHERE TypeOrModel ='Axis';
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='499' WHERE TypeOrModel ='B100';    
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='499' WHERE TypeOrModel ='B5';    
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='499' WHERE TypeOrModel ='B8';
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='499' WHERE TypeOrModel ='Breeze';
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='499' WHERE TypeOrModel ='Breeze 2';
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='499' WHERE TypeOrModel ='Bubble';
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price='499' WHERE TypeOrModel ='Burst 2.0';
```

Comment: any help or other response is highly appreciated.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use below quwery will solve your problem.

```
update tblstoreitems
set price = 
case 
when TypeOrModel  = 'A130' then 499
when TypeOrModel  = 'A140' then 599
when TypeOrModel  = 'Alpha Style' then 1899
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are updating the column `price` with different `TypeOrModel` values and if you want it to be in a single statement, you can use `case when` within the update something as

```
update tblstoreitems
set 
price = 
case 
 when TypeOrModel = 'A130' then '499'
 when TypeOrModel = 'A140' then '599'
 .......
 .......
 when TypeOrModel ='Burst 2.0' then '499'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace these updates with a single update using a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE tblstoreitems 
SET    price = CASE TypeOrModel
                WHEN 'A130' THEN '499'
                WHEN 'A140' THEN '599'
                -- All the others cases, snipped for clarity
                ELSE price END;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
UPDATE tblstoreitems SET price=
CASE WHEN TypeOrModel IN 
(
    'A130','Aura Fusion','Axis','B100','B5','B8',
    'Breeze','Breeze 2','Bubble','Burst 2.0'
)
THEN 499
WHEN TypeOrModel IN ('A140') THEN 599
WHEN TypeOrModel IN ('Alpha Style') THEN 1899
WHEN TypeOrModel IN ('Amethyst') THEN 1699
WHEN TypeOrModel IN ('T18') THEN 899
WHEN TypeOrModel IN ('Ace_f100') THEN 1499
ELSE price
END;
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f15e6/1)**

Comment: This will nullify the price for any model not treated in one of the `when` expressions.